# Why does AsyncPipe evaluate differently in {{}} and *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

```
<div *ngIf="!!(result$ | async)">
    {{!!(result$ | async)}}
</div>
```

I expect it to be blank and then show `true`. Surprisingly, it shows `false` and then `true`. Is there a different evaluation mechanism for `{{}}` and `*ngIf`? The `result$` is of type `Observable<{ products: any[] }>`.

```
constructor() {
    this.result$ = Observable.of("Dummy!").delay(3000);
}
```

Angular2 release version

Comment: Could you post the implementation of myService.getResult function?

Comment: @HarryNinh Here is he implementation

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that the structural directives are evaluated at ViewInit and interpoltaions at ContentInit

Comment: @snolflake Good point! Do you have a recommended way to display child control only when parent's `this.childData$` has arrived? Because last time as soon as data arrived, it displayed child control, but child control's binding `<my-child [data]="this.childData$">` still passed null.

Comment: childData$ is an `@Input()` ? Provide more pieces of your real code, it will be easier to help...

Comment: I guess I need a separate question for that :)

Comment: That's weird, I have this plnkr with different type of Observable and it's working as expected: http://plnkr.co/edit/rh1eUFziMxBjZQg3OKLN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reason is that observable in `result$` is cold and gets rerun every time its called. And there are two calls for `result$ | async` in my markup. I either need to create an actual variable to store the value on subscription or add `share` operator to observable to prevent rerunning.

There is an [issue on github](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2451) for workarounds.